# asp.net Gridview ImageField alternate Image

Tags: asp.net, gridview, imagefield

I have below gridview with an imagefield linked with the UserID number.
How can I do if the picture dosnt exist in the specifield older to get an standard alternate picture?

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="MainPic" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("PerfilId") as string)%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
```

..

```
    protected string GetImageUrl(string dbImgURL)
    {
        if (File.Exists(dbImgURL))
        {
            return dbImgURL;
        }
        else
        {
            return "AdminFotoUser/UserPics/BGP1.png";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you can check the image path in onRowDataBound event of the GridView and change it to a common image if file doesn't exist.
using System.IO;

```
if (File.Exists(path)) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("file exists");
                }
```

else
   //Find Control and Bind it to a common image

**OR**

You could have re-worked your grid a different way:
- instead of using an Image Field column, you could have used a template column like this:
Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImg"
            ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval(col2) as string) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in your code behind, you have create a function to return the correct image url:
Code:
**Updated Ans**

```
//Send Image name from database (DataGrid) as dbImgURL
protected string GetImageUrl(string dbImgURL)
{
   if (File.Exists(dbImgURL)) 
    {
       return dbImgURL;          
    }
   else
    {
       return "Green.gif";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was what I was looking for. one mor thing. If the picture existes in the file and I want the gridview to use the existing picture how I will have to replace the >return "Green.gif"<

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still get back only the "Green.gif" and not the "if return".  :-)   (update my question)

Comment: @RMU I dont know what do you want to achieve..Its quite simple logic..Simple if else nothing more .... If DataBaseImage Exists Then Use DataBaseImage  ........>>ELSE Use Green (N/A) image